# FUNCTION db_table.sys_exec does not exist

Tags: mysql

I am using godaddy shared hosting and trying to invoke an PHP placed on the same server to accomplish this i had created a trigger to respective table, below is the code

```
DELIMITER @@

CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);
DECLARE result int(10);
SET cmd=CONCAT('/usr/bin/php ', '/home/public_html/domain/index.php  controller function');
SET result = sys_exec(cmd);

END;
@@
DELIMITER ;
```

but i am getting an error  "FUNCTION db_table.sys_exec does not exist".
Would be appreciated if someone helps me to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

`sys_exec` needs the [UDF plugin](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys#readme) to work, and it must be installed separately.